# How to normalize by another row in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble finding the non-for loop version of this. Say this is my input:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]: 
        N  experiment   color  value    value2
0  145000           0     red   0.30  0.363953
1   14000           1     red   0.31  0.218978
2   13000           2     red   0.29  0.948070
3   15000           0  yellow   0.31  0.620201
4    1200           1  yellow   0.32  0.567513
5    1400           2  yellow   0.31  0.318197
6   40000           0   green   0.29  0.947226
7    3000           1   green   0.31  0.084243
8    7000           2   green   0.32  0.961020

[9 rows x 5 columns]
```

Experiment 0 is my control. I performed this experiment for various colors. I want to normalize all rows by the matching color experiment 0.

```
In [104]: df
Out[104]: 
        N  experiment   color  value    value2  scaled_value  scaled_value2
0  145000           0     red   0.30  0.363953      1.000000       1.000000
1   14000           1     red   0.31  0.218978      1.033333       0.590786
2   13000           2     red   0.29  0.948070      0.966667       2.604732
3   15000           0  yellow   0.31  0.620201      1.000000       1.000000
4    1200           1  yellow   0.32  0.567513      1.032258       0.914220
5    1400           2  yellow   0.31  0.318197      1.000000       0.512737
6   40000           0   green   0.29  0.947226      1.000000       1.000000
7    3000           1   green   0.31  0.084243      1.068966       0.088680
8    7000           2   green   0.32  0.961020      1.103448       1.014541

[9 rows x 7 columns]
```

It seems I would want to exact the experiment zero parameters to their own column to permit easy division, but I can't get the stacking/pivoting/concat'ing to work properly. I did this with for loops using .at and assigning values but it felt so wrong.

The next steps would be normalizing several columns and creating upplower and lower error bounds calculated from (N, value), (N, value2), (N, other_values) etc.

Comment: Look into `sklearn`'s `MinMaxScaler`; I would image they've optimized the vector operations. Also pretty sure you can feed it `pandas` data http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: @Ryan, isn't that for scaling the values in a single column/array? When I say normalize, I don't mean the vector ranges (0,1), but that each is divided by an outside value.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use `transform` (here using `idxmin`, although there are many alternatives) to get the indices of the rows we want to use as the denominator:

```
>>> ii = df.groupby("color")["experiment"].transform("idxmin")
>>> cols = ["value", "value2"]
>>> new_cols = (df.loc[:,cols] /df.loc[ii, cols].values)
>>> df.join(new_cols.rename(columns=lambda x: "scaled_" + x))
        N  experiment   color  value    value2  scaled_value  scaled_value2
0  145000           0     red   0.30  0.363953      1.000000       1.000000
1   14000           1     red   0.31  0.218978      1.033333       0.601666
2   13000           2     red   0.29  0.948070      0.966667       2.604924
3   15000           0  yellow   0.31  0.620201      1.000000       1.000000
4    1200           1  yellow   0.32  0.567513      1.032258       0.915047
5    1400           2  yellow   0.31  0.318197      1.000000       0.513055
6   40000           0   green   0.29  0.947226      1.000000       1.000000
7    3000           1   green   0.31  0.084243      1.068966       0.088937
8    7000           2   green   0.32  0.961020      1.103448       1.014563
```

---

Step by step, first we find the denominator indices:

```
>>> ii = df.groupby("color")["experiment"].transform("idxmin")
>>> ii
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    6
7    6
8    6
dtype: int64
```

Then we can use this to index into the frame:

```
>>> df.loc[ii, cols]
   value    value2
0   0.30  0.363953
0   0.30  0.363953
0   0.30  0.363953
3   0.31  0.620201
3   0.31  0.620201
3   0.31  0.620201
6   0.29  0.947226
6   0.29  0.947226
6   0.29  0.947226
```

Since we're handling the alignment ourselves, we need to call `.values` to drop down to the underlying array-- otherwise pandas will try to outsmart us and align things correctly based on the indices.

Then we divide:

```
>>> (df.loc[:,cols] /df.loc[ii, cols].values)
      value    value2
0  1.000000  1.000000
1  1.033333  0.601666
2  0.966667  2.604924
3  1.000000  1.000000
4  1.032258  0.915047
5  1.000000  0.513055
6  1.000000  1.000000
7  1.068966  0.088937
8  1.103448  1.014563
```

and finally join them, renaming the new columns:

```
>>> df.join(new_cols.rename(columns=lambda x: "scaled_" + x))
        N  experiment   color  value    value2  scaled_value  scaled_value2
0  145000           0     red   0.30  0.363953      1.000000       1.000000
1   14000           1     red   0.31  0.218978      1.033333       0.601666
2   13000           2     red   0.29  0.948070      0.966667       2.604924
3   15000           0  yellow   0.31  0.620201      1.000000       1.000000
4    1200           1  yellow   0.32  0.567513      1.032258       0.915047
5    1400           2  yellow   0.31  0.318197      1.000000       0.513055
6   40000           0   green   0.29  0.947226      1.000000       1.000000
7    3000           1   green   0.31  0.084243      1.068966       0.088937
8    7000           2   green   0.32  0.961020      1.103448       1.014563
```